# Whats the difference between @var@ and %var% in batch scripting?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, environment-variables

While working on my project at work, I came across a startup script for the application which just kind of sets up all the environment variable, paths that sort of thing. I see variables assigned to values like this

```
set abc=%def%
```

and also like this:

```
set xyz=@pqr@
```

Whats the difference between using @xxxx@ against %xxxx% ? I haven't done any batch scripting but looked around could not find an answer to this strangely.

Comment: `%def%` is a variable. It has a value - or not. The parser replaces it with it's value. `@pqr@` is just a string with length=5. `@` has no special meaning in batch - it's just a character like `a` or `x`.

Comment: Unless it's at the beginning of a line, then `@` means "run this command without printing the command first" when echo is on.

Comment: I'd like to know where you've seen `@` for variable expansion, it's just wrong. There is `%VAR%` and – when [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is enabled – `!VAR!`, that's it…

Answer (score 0):

`%` marks things as variables, which you can set, change, and read, (You can also use `!` if delayed expansion is enabled.) while `@` is just a character, which will print as is and is not used for variables.